# Login script not redirecting, Receiving blank page

Tags: php, web, authentication

I have tested my login by using the following script on my index.php file,

```
 <?php 
  include 'core/init.php';
 ?>
<html>
 <?php 
 if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
     echo 'logged in';
     } else {
         echo 'Not Logged In';
 }
 ?>
```

So at first the page displays, 'not logged in' but when email and password is entered correctly the page is supposed to redirect to the index.php page. But instead I am getting a blank page when running the login.php file. I have to manually change the page back to index.php, where then it says 'logged in'.

Heres my Login.php script:

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';


if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($email) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a email and password';
} else if (user_exists($email) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that email. Have you registered?';
} else if (user_active($email) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account!';
} else {

    if (strlen($password) > 32) {
        $errors[] = 'Password too long';
    }

    $login = login($email, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
        $errors[] = 'That email/password combination is incorrect';
    } else {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
        header('Location: Index.php');
        exit();         
    }
}
  print_r($errors);

 }
 ?>
```

My Login.php file includes another file called init.php which I start the session;

```
<?php
session_start();


require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

$errors = array();
?>
```

An update, I have created a logout.php file to log the user out which redirects to the index.php file. Logout.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

PS - I am new to PHP ad there may be a small error I am overlooking, any feedback or comments are welcome. Thanks (Y)

Comment: Post your functions also.

Comment: Where are you starting the sessions (`session_start()`)?

Comment: `Index.php` != `index.php`

Comment: Sorry, My login.php file includes another file called init.php, I have edited my post to include that file.

Comment: If `session_start();` is not inside ALL your files, start by doing that. It's not shown/mentioned in your first body of code (index.php)

Comment: *"I have tested my login by using the following script on my index.php file"* `<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {` is `session_start();` not in this page?

Comment: How are you doing the redirect? If you are echoing "logged in" and then using `header()` to redirect that will throw a fatal error since you can't set headers after outputting to page

Comment: Well the login.php script is supposed to run then redirect back to index.php, where then I am echoing 'logged in' or 'logged out' depending if it was successful.

If the details are incorrect a message is shown saying why, and when details are right then I'm supposed to be redirected. When details are right I am logged in I just have to go back to index.php manually.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things about your code:

1. It doesn't seem you are starting the session anywhere.
2. I would recommend against using file names like `Index.php`, use `index.php` instead (just an advice, not necessarily a problem)
3. Does the url change in the browser? I mean is the redirect taking effect, but redirect to a non existing/blank page, or the url remains the same? If remains the same means your code never hit's the redirection, if it changes means the `Index.php` doesn't exists.

UPDATE!

In case of successfully login you are redirecting, but in case of errors you are not showing the errors.

At the end of `login.php` do a `print_r($errors)`, to see them.
The redirect probably doesn't happen, because the authentication failed.

Comment: For 1), he posted the contents of `core/init.php`, the session is started there.

Comment: I didn't noticed that. Thanks for notifying about the update.

Comment: 2) My index.php file was in non caps, I have changed the redirect code so it is also index.php. (Still does not redirect).
3) The URL changed to login.php and then goes nowhere and displays a blank page. index.php does exist in the same folder :/

Comment: [**He's over here now...**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533105/changing-dropdown-form-on-my-navigation-bar-when-user-is-logged-in) ;-) @TamasPap

Comment: I doubt you'll hear from the OP at this point in time. Your answer makes sense, however I doubt the OP knows what's going on here. @TamasPap

Comment: @TamasPap Thanks, I did originally have 'code' print_R($errors) 'code',
I have updated the login script above, I am not getting any errors but yet my logout.php script still runs and redirects to the same index.php file. I have included the logout.php above.